# C# generic class type parameter as method argument type for GRPC generated class

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, grpc, generic-programming

I have the following interface:

```
interface IGrpcClient<TMessage>
{
    Task Handle(TMessage message);
}
```

and implementation class:

```
class GrpcClient<TMessage> : IGrpcClient<TMessage>
{
    public async Task Handle(TMessage message)
    {
        GrpcGreeter.HelloReply response = await _client.SayHelloAsync(message);
    }
}
```

and tried to pass the `IMessage` object from `Progam.cs` into the method:

```
await grpcClient.Handle(new HelloRequest() {Name = "Donald Trump"});
```

results in the following compilation error:

```
GrpcClient.cs(27,75): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TMessage' to 'GrpcGreeter.HelloRequest' [/usr/src/GRPC/Greeter/src/GrpcClient/GrpcClient.csproj]
```

`HellloRequest`, which is `TMessage`, is auto generated from .proto file using .Net Core 3.0.

What do I miss? Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Auto-generated function:

```
public virtual grpc::AsyncUnaryCall<global::GrpcGreeter.HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(global::GrpcGreeter.HelloRequest request, grpc::Metadata headers = null, global::System.DateTime? deadline = null, global::System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(global::System.Threading.CancellationToken))
{
    return SayHelloAsync(request, new grpc::CallOptions(headers, deadline, cancellationToken));
}
public virtual grpc::AsyncUnaryCall<global::GrpcGreeter.HelloReply> SayHelloAsync(global::GrpcGreeter.HelloRequest request, grpc::CallOptions options)
{
    return CallInvoker.AsyncUnaryCall(__Method_SayHello, null, options, request);
}
```

Comment: Can you add at least signature of _client.SayHelloAsync method? Because I'm guessing it's parameter is HelloRequest and you can't convert TMessage (which can be anything basically) to HelloRequest.

Comment: Updated my post with the signature.

Comment: We'd need to see the signature of `_client.SayHelloAsync`. The parameter of `SayHelloAsync` has to be a base-class of `HelloRequest`. When you have that you can restrict the typeparam `TMessage` to derive from that base-class. Post the signature of `SayHelloAsync` and I can post an answer :)

Comment: That's exactly what I have posted here, the signature of SayHelloAsync.

Comment: My bad I got lost in the grpc stuff. Why are you using generics then? Obviously the client you're using only accepts `HelloRequest` and doesn't support generic messages. You could in theory do `where TMessage : HelloRequest` to restrict `TMessage` to derive from `HelloRequest` but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for if you're using generics, right? If you had a base-class of `HelloRequest` and the auto-generated methods would use that, you could restrict `TMessage` to derive from that base-class which is probably what you're looking for. You'd need to change the code-generation.

Comment: GRPC does NOT support Inheritance. I would have to accept `object` in my interface then.

Comment: If it doesn't support inheritance then ~~~generics are not the right call~~~ you have to make the GRPC client accept `object`. You can still use generics to wrap the client (like you do in your example) but the client itself has to be able to handle `object`.